# Domain Alias with forward in plesk

Tags: plesk, domain-forwarding

I need to create a domain alias `alias.domain.com` to forward http to `www.domain.com`.

It has to be a forward and not a redirect (I was told it can be done by creating CNAME).

Note I am using Plesk and creating a domain alias in plesk creates an A record not a CNAME.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider...

```
bar.example.com.        CNAME  foo.example.com.
foo.example.com.        A      192.0.2.23
```

Here,

1. when a `DNS resolver` encounters a `CNAME record` while looking for a regular resource record, it will restart the query using the canonical name instead of the original name.
2. That is when an `A record` lookup for `bar.example.com` is done, the resolver will see a `CNAME record` and restart the checking at `foo.example.com` and will then return `192.0.2.23`.

In Plesk, when we create a domain alias, actually it adds `ServerAlias alias.domain.com` in vhost configurations of httpd, and hence the `A record`. Read [Here](http://kb.parallels.com/en/894) and try relating with [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

As a matter of fact `alias.domain.com` is resolving directly to pointing IP address, restarting of query is not required is in `CNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between a forward and a redirect. What you mean is probably the function called "Redirection" in Plesk and that function needs to be enabled by your host to show up. If it's not there, ask your hoster to enable it for you.

If Plesk (or your hoster) doesn't help you out, you may need to add this to your root-folder's .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^alias.domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

If your host gives you 500 error, remove the hash from the third line. That ought to do it.